# How to align Object Mesh when using Mirror Modifier?

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

When I add a [`Mirror Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html) to an object, I need to align the mesh so I can properly join the mirrored mesh with the original object mesh. I always have difficulties in the alignment. Is there a way or command that automatically aligns the mirrored mesh?

Comment: I'd suggest that you watch a good tutorial on using the Mirror modifier such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAaOOCragLc) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method would be to position the [`Object Origin`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/origin.html) (orange dot) on the flat end side so that when you do the mirror it will perfectly align. First make sure you're in *Edit Mode* and make sure there is no face (delete it if there is) then [`Select Edge Loop`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/selecting/loops.html) of the open end you want to merge with the other mirrored mesh. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select *Cursor to Selected*. Then press <kbd>tab</kbd> to return to *Object Mode* and click <kbd>RMB</kbd> (right click) *> Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*. Now the Mirror Modifier will perfectly join both ends of the mesh if you have correctly set the X,Y, or Z Axis.

[image]