# Mirror modifier on plane is not working properly

Tags: mirror-modifier

Why when i added mirror modifier to the plane, it is not working as i want, i want it to reflect along the design but it taking weird direction

Why? & How to rectify it?

[image]

After applying the mirror modifier does the new mirror plane appears in same exact place at opposite angle or it appears at a distance from original plane

How it happens to you? Please clarify.

[image]

Comment: First thing, in Object mode press Ctrl A > Apply Rotation

Comment: can u clear the second doubt i posted please

Comment: Can anyone please tell me based on what this question is called as duplicate and made it close. Please give the reasons so that i can understand for my future questions

Comment: please share your file: https://blenderartists.org/c/support/9

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273033/how-to-align-object-mesh-when-using-mirror-modifier